# Custom post type - permalink

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, metabox

Is it possible to change the permalink of a custom posttype?

I have a custom post type called "events", I have made a page called archive-event.php and this is reached by /event.php

is it possible to change this into something else? Like /foo.php?

Comment: It's impossible to understand what you are asking about. Please clarify.

Comment: @MaxYudin - I have created a custom post type called event and have created a page called archive-event to access all posts under "event". To access this page I go to */event but now I want to change this to */foo.

Comment: Edit the archive page through the admin panel and change the slug of the archive page to `foo` and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

When you [register your post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) you can set the archive page slug to anything you want via the `rewrite` or `has_archive` arguments.

If you want single events to have the same slug as the archive, you can set both via:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'foo' )
```

Or if you want the archive to have a different slug, set that separately via `has_archive`:

```
'has_archive' => 'foo'
```

Comment: this doesnt work for me?

register_post_type('event',
  array(
   'labels' => array(
    'name' => __('Händelser'),
    'singular_name' => __('Händelse')
   ),
   'public' => true,
   'has_archive' => 'foo',
   'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'custom-fields', 'page-attributes')
  )

 );

Comment: Your code works for me in Twenty Eleven theme, make sure you visit your Settings > Permalinks page after adding the post type to flush the rewrite rules. Single events are available at `domain.com/event/post-name/` and the archive is available at `domain.com/foo/`.